# posts notifications starting point

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, notifications

I really need your advice guys. I've made up posting chat with Php,MySql,jQuery (Users can post some messages). I've searched a lot but nothing found interesting which would be good starting point for notifications. I want to when for example user1 writes msg if user2 is not logged in I could notify user2 when this last will log in. Any idea how is it possible to do that ?

PS. I am thinking of to accomplish this task by datetimes, I've datetimes when msg is posted, but don't know how to connect with users, maybe with logged out time , but I guess it impossible to get exactly right time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want an observer system. Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) wikipedia article.

Also, check out [Pusher](http://pusher.com/).

Comment: I've notified with push technology, but can't find any normal tutorial for that . Is it possible to make up server push with only php,mysql,jquery ? And maybe you know some good tutorial or article ? thanks

Comment: Well, you can fire ajax requests every few seconds/minutes, check for new logins and then display them to the user.